# Spring-Boot apps installed as Service in linux cannot share postgresql database

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, spring-boot, debian

I have two different runnable Spring-Boot applications that share the same local postgresql database schema. If I start one while the other is running, the previous one crashes and stops immediatelly.

Both applications are runnable Spring-Boot Thymeleaf web applications. Application1 generates content and saves it into the database. Application2 reads it from the same database and generates export files.

Each application connects itself to the database with different credentials. User1 has the ownership of the tables and all privileges. User2 has all privileges on all the tables.

Both are also configured to run in different ports.

**Application1 - application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database-name
    username: application1-user
    password: application1-password
server:
  port: 8000
```

**Application2 - application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database-name
    username: application2-user
    password: application2-password
server:
  port: 8002
```

Each one of them is owned in the file system by user1 and user2 respectively.

When I run each of them in different terminals with their specific user through the command line they start gracefully, access the tables inside the database and work as expected.

**Application1 - terminal 1**

```
sudo su user1
java -jar application1
```

**Application2 - terminal 2**

```
sudo su user2
java -jar application2
```

They are both succcessfully installed as a Service on a Linux Debian server. Both of them can start individually as Service flawlessly. But when I run one as a Service while the other is already running as a Service, the active one crashes and stops completely.

```
sudo service application1 start
sudo service application1 status *(active)*
sudo service application2 start
sudo service application2 status *(active, application2 stops immediatelly)*
```

When the first application crashes and stops, no new line is written on the log, so I cannot know the reason why it stops or read any exception that might be thrown. However, my guess is that it has something to do with Linux and not with the applications themselves.

This is the only information I could find out from the Service log.

```
sudo service application1 status
(...)
Aug 06 07:02:07 server application1.jar[18990]: /var/apps/application1/application1.jar: line 214: 19001 Killed                  "$javaexe" "${arguments[@]}"
Aug 06 07:02:07 server systemd[1]: application1.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=137/n/a
Aug 06 07:02:07 server systemd[1]: Unit application1.service entered failed state.
```

This is the code I wrote inside the systemctl files.

**Application1 - application1.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=application1
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=user1
ExecStart=/var/apps/application1/application1.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Application2 - application2.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=application2
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=user2
ExecStart=/var/apps/application2/application2.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How can I achieve running both at the same time as a Service? Is there something I am missing?

Thank you very much in advance for your time.

Comment: A "crashing" Spring Boot application will have a detailed error report and/or stack trace. Post it.

Comment: I monitored both application logs and nothing is reported there during the shut down of the first one. As a reminder, both applications can run perfectly in parallel if I run them through different terminals. It is just that they won't work together when run as a Service. I post below the log lines that the command service status reports.

Comment: `code`Aug 06 07:02:07 server application1.jar[18990]: /var/apps/application1/application1.jar: line 214: 19001 Killed                  "$javaexe" "${arguments[@]}"
Aug 06 07:02:07 server systemd[1]: application1.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=137/n/a
Aug 06 07:02:07 server systemd[1]: Unit application1.service entered failed state.`code`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided, it could just be that they are both launched with the default port, thus conflicting ?

add this to one application:

```
server.port = 8081
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, i forgot to say that both are already setup to run in different ports. I will edit the question to clarify.